# Rails: Routing Error, comment model to micropost model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, post, routes

I made a commenting system and I am trying to get it to post under a micropost but I constantly get this routing error. Any suggestions? All help is much appreciated!

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/microposts/comments"
```

**Form**

```
<div class="CommentField">
<%= form_for ([@micropost, @micropost.comments.new]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "CommentButton b1" %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**comment controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save 
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

**routes**

```
resources :microposts do
  resources :comments
end
```

**Micropost Model**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :view_count
  acts_as_voteable
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :views
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the action that is rendering the above form?

Comment: I'm looking for the `new` method, or some equivalent, from a controller. Wherever `@micropost` is being set.

Comment: @Deefour it is all shown on the user controller which can be found here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is that you are trying to build a form for a `comments` of a `micropost` that does not exist yet in the database.

the form, there is a -

```
   form_for ([@micropost, @micropost.comments.new]) do |f|
```

And in UsersController you have -

```
  @micropost = Micropost.new
```

comment is a sub-resource of micropost, so a url that creates a comment should look like `/micropost/:id/comments` where :id is the id of micropost. That is possible only after the micropost is saved.

So I believe your action should assign `@micropost` to an existing post, or create one right there to have the form working. Something like -

```
   @micropost = Micropost.last || Micropost.create
```

would at least get rid of the error.

Comment: would i be entering this into the user controller where `@micropost = Micropost.new` this is?

Comment: Yes. Actually the controller-action that renders the form code you posted.

Comment: yes I added it to the user controller which shows the micropost and the comments are suppose to be there as well but I am now greeted with this error now 


`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in CommentsController#create

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments_count: UPDATE "microposts" SET "comments_count" = COALESCE("comments_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "microposts"."id" IN (SELECT "microposts"."id" FROM "microposts"  WHERE "microposts"."id" = 1 ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC)`

`app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:6:in `create'`

Comment: That may be an unrelated problem, perhaps about `counter_cache`. Please check for it in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll try this again *(deleted my other answer since, as Marc Talbot pointed out, was not the correct response to your issue)*.

Perhaps the issue is as simple as making `:microposts` be `:micropost` instead *(to reflect your model's name)*.

```
resources :micropost do
  resources :comments
end
```